# Cannot connect Parse with Android Studio

Tags: parse-platform

Everything works fine but when I build my Parse app, it generates the following event log entry :

> ****Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2****

I don't understand what to do to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have exceeded 65k method limit. Add following changes  in `build.gradle` file

```
 defaultConfig 
   {
     multiDexEnabled true
      }
```